# Why is android.database.SQLException unchecked?

Tags: java, android, sqlexception

This might be unsuitable for SO since it isn't really a coding-problem, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer yet and I believe the SO-community can.

So, by definition [android.database.SQLException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html) and [java.sql.SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) share about the same scope of application, which is to provide information about errors while accessing/modifying a database. Though I've read somewhere that checked exceptions are "out", I really like the fact that the compiler reminds you of handling exceptions when you use checked exceptions with the `throws` keyword. Unfortunately this doesn't work with unchecked exceptions.

My question is: 
Why did Google make their `android.database.SQLException` unchecked when `java.sql.SQLException` is checked? Am I missing something? Do they differ more than I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice between making an exception checked or unchecked is always somewhat subjective:

- If an exception indicates a bug, or some failure that is "probably not recoverable", then a unchecked exception is appropriate.
- If an exception indicates a failure that is "probably recoverable", then a checked exception is appropriate.

It is more difficult in cases like this where there is a general exception with lots of subclasses.  Some of those subclasses *could be* bugs, or they *could be* recoverable.  At this point, the designer has to make a value judgement about the relative likelihood of the different cases ... across all known / predicted subtypes of the exception.

In this case, the Sun and Google engineers came to different conclusions.  But note that the Google engineers had a big advantage that the Sun engineers didn't have.  They could look at the Java design, and make their own judgement on how well it worked with a checked `SQLException`.

---

> Though I've read somewhere that checked exceptions are "out" ...

There are a lot of developers who wish that all Java exceptions were unchecked so that they didn't have to be forced to deal with them.  There are a lot of other developers who still think that Java got it right with checked exceptions ... even though there were a few cases where the wrong choice was made (in hindsight).

It is debatable.

> Am I missing something? Do they differ more than I think?

Not really.  The two exception hierarchies serve pretty much the same purpose ... differences in javadoc class descriptions notwithstanding.

Comment: I know I can't expect a perfect answer on this question since it is about a subjective decision someone made. But your answer contains some major points about the choice between checked and unchecked exceptions, which I didn't thought of yet, so I'll accept it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

`android.database.SQLException` is based on [`java.lang.RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and don't need to be checked, but `java.sql.SQLException` isn't.

At [Unchecked Exceptions — The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) there is a simple explanation about this.

Comment: I know the basic difference between checked and unchecked exceptions in java when it comes to inheritance, so your answer isn't really what I was looking for. However, the link you posted contains some useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that unchecked Exceptions are to prefer over checked Exceptions in many cases. The reason is that you aren't *forced* to catch it in any way. You can surround your code with a `try-catch` clause if you think it's necessary, but you don't have to. This effectively makes your code better, as the programmer can decide what to do.

In your example, **there is no particular reason** why one has to make it `checked` or not. It is a question of design, whereby I think Google did a better job with `android.database.SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think it is so is because :

> android.database.SQLException : An exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution.

and

> java.sql.SQLException : An exception that provides information on a database access error or other errors.

So, it is clear that `android.database.SQLException` is likely a `RuntimeException` because it occurs when there is an error with SQL parsing or execution.
Whereas, `java.sql.SQLException` is an exception caused due to database access error or other such errors, so it is valid enough to keep it as a checked exception. Anytime you work with open connections, or any things of such sort, it's better to have them under the umbrella of checked exception.

Comment: I understand why android's exception should be a RuntimeException but what makes the difference to java's exception? I mean, in android it will also be thrown when the program cannot connect to the database, so isn't this as "valid" as the other one? PS: If I post links you can expect me to have taken a look at them ;)